# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in 15

Tags: mysql, sql, environment-variables

I have following query

```
$sql=" UPDATE reg_voters_t SET county='$county', constituency='$constituency', regcenter='$regcenter' WHERE IDNo='$IDNo'";
```

When i run above query i am getting this error-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in 15

Answer (score 6):

the problem probably is that the line before your SQL query is missing semicolon (;). The error begins in $sql so it has to be something before.

```
$a = 10
$sql = "UPDATE reg_voters_t SET county='$county', constituency='$constituency', regcenter='$regcenter' WHERE IDNo='$IDNo'";
```

> line before code containing '$sql' declaration is missing semicolon